# How to clear css rules inside specific div for external js embedded content. I mean make it behave as there was no previous css rules present?

Tags: javascript, html, css, maps

I want to embed zumi.pl map on my website. Their map is loaded via js to div with specific id and is dependent on external css. However my css for formating div inside `div#content` interferes with embedded map screwing it all up. I tried [to enclose it in another div with contextual css reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) but it's still displays wrong. Only way to make it display (almost) properly is to uncheck all my css rules for that div in firefox inspector but I can't figure it out how to achieve the same effect on page.
for clarity this is sample copy&paste code from their generator:

```
    <div id="zumiMap" class="zumi_creator" style="width:300px; height:300px;"></div>
<script src="http://api.zumi.pl/maps/api" type="text/javascript" ></script><script type="text/javascript">(function(){var marker,map=new zumi.maps.Map("zumiMap", {"apiKey": "E48EF8E55A0B3BEAE0434628AE0A1EEA"});map.afterLoad(function() {document.getElementById("zumiMap").className += " zumi_creator";map.addMarker({lat: 52.214679,lng: 21.021101},{letter: "A", type: "main"});map.setCenter({lng: 21.021101,lat: 52.214679}, 7);});})();</script>
```

and here is my css that's to blame:

```
#content div {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0.833333%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

How to isolate html  fragment so it behaves as there was no previous css rules present?
But without using Iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?  `#content #zumiMap div` will have higher specificity than your `#content div` selector, so you can reset all the problem styles.

```
#content #zumiMap div {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```